# Typescript: how to import javascript methods when targetting both ES2015 and COMMONJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, commonjs

In a typescript source file, I use a library xml-formatter that way:

```
import format = require('xml-formatter')
...
let formatted = format( myXml )
```

As `xml-formatter` library has no typescript definition file, I set `noImplicitAny = false` in the tsconfig.json to allow it.

My app compiles and works when targetting COMMONJS. But when targetting ES2015 for bundling my app, the following error is returned when compiling with the command `ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json`:

> Error at C:/Projets/IMASentinel/app/history-app.ts:5:1: Import assignment cannot be used when target modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', format instead.

I tried using the syntax described in the error:

```
import xmlformatter from "xml-formatter" 
or  import * as xmlformatter from "xml-formatter" 
or  import format from "xml-formatter" 
...

let formatted = xmlformatter.format( myXml )
```

.. but the method xmlformatter.format is not found at runtime: because the mothod expoerted is only format without the xmlformatter namespace.

In the xml-formatter library, the method format is exported that way:

```
function format( xml, options ) { ... }
module.exports = format;
```

Comment: You could use an cjs-to-es6 converter: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cjs-to-es6 (I haven't tried it, but it looks promising)

Comment: Why don't you just use the plain old syntax instead: `const format = require('xml-formatter')`? As you've said you don't have any definitions anyway.

Comment: Yes that's the solution I found for now. In dev environment, I use systemjs, but in prod environment, the counterpart is I need to include the whole 'xml-formatter' script files and their dependencies in index.html.  If I could use an import statement, rollup would bundle the used methods in my bundle.js application file.